Unable to build the serve the project in Angular v14
Unable to do ng serve in the angularv14 project. Able to build the file and get the dist but when I try to do ng serve it gives the below error.
Error which I'm getting.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:      
  Data path "" must have required property 'browserTarget'.  

Here is build and serve object of angular.json file of project.

            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
         },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
             },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:qa"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:dev"
            }
          }
         },



